# What is the simple way to create a full screen img gallery

Tags: jquery, css, fullscreen, image-gallery

I'm trying to create a simple, (but) full screen img gallery, and adopted the first solution from [this article](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

So, the code is:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

And I have some js code to change (onclick) the background attr of html - it works.

Two question:

- What about img quality on a monitor larger then 1024x768 (that's the size of my monitor and the size of all images)
- What about img proportion on a monitor with the different aspect ratio ? The image will probably look deformed ?

Is there any simple (css or jquery solution) ?

Comment: there are probably hundreds of plugins available for JQuery image gallery. Try searching major search engines (Google, Bing..).

Comment: background:cover ensures that the image is not deformed. Some of the image will get cut off if the ratio is not that of the original image. Your solution about image quality will be to upload higher quality images/use higher dpi images, or deal with it. You can't make something out of nothing - so enlarging an image larger than it's original will always have some negative affect.

Comment: you should probably use Media Queries to detect screen resolution and deliver different images to scale.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, using `Media Queries` - must I have two (or more) distances of the sameimage uploaded for different monitors ?

Comment: @SunSky that is correct. you would need to have multiple images. Most devices these days spit them out around 2960x2100 or something near there (I forget the exact values). This allows you to scale down pretty aesily. While it does force you to have a lot of space taken up on your drive, most good hosts these days don't worry about rack space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image quality can only be as good as the image you are loading. That is, if your image is 1024x768, it will look great on anything at or below that resolution. On browsers or displays with higher resolutions, the image will be scaled, stretching pixels larger than 1:1 and causing some loss in quality. I would advise you to use the largest images you can, or use `@media` queries to serve larger images to larger displays and smaller images to smaller ones to save load time.

On your second point, the cover directive of background-size is designed to handle issues with aspect ratios and sizing, allowing the browser to show the maximum amount of your image, in it's correct ratio, in the available space. Could you elaborate on the issue you're having?

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I understand (think so) - then must say - Ugh. I will try `Media Query`. Let's say - Solved.